# MySQL log_visitor insert

Tags: database, magento-1, query, log, magento-ee

I seem to be having loads of problems with this table in my Magento EE 1.14 build.

I'm curious to know about what the stack community things about turning it off and the repercussions associated with disabling.

I found a brief article that suggested something like so:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <controller_action_postdispatch>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch>
        <customer_login>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
        <checkout_quote_destroy>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </checkout_quote_destroy>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

I found this information here: http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/12/how-to-disable-magento-logging-to-the-database/

Will this break "The product comparing" if I disable the visitor log?

What else should I know about?

New Relic keeps telling me this is a problem every night at the same time.

[image]

What should/can i do to improve this process. I've set the log to clean every day. I can't understand why it's taking so long for the insert.

```
   Slow query trace
437,000ms
MAX TIME
/cms/page/view
ACTION
Query
 INSERT INTO `log_visitor` (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`, `store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

437,000ms.... that's like 7+ minutes of downtime. Need help, please.

Comment: What's the size of your `core_session` table?